# Hide the item with NULL value while triggering Email from Oracle APEX

Tags: oracle-apex

I am developing an application using APEX 5.0

An Email is triggered when we click on a button. Few Items have null value but still appear in the Email as i have linked them. How do i hide the item with NULL value while triggering Email from Oracle APEX. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Format email body text using PLSQL as per your requirement and then set it into a page item which can then be referred in Email Process using substitution string.

Based on your comments, looks like you are using **PL/SQL Code** process type and not **Send E-Mail** process type in your Submit process.

Lets say you have 3 page items that may have NULL values. Modify your code in following way to display items in body which have values.

```
DECLARE
  L_BODY   VARCHAR2(32767);
  L_FOOTER VARCHAR2(32767);
  FUNCTION FORMAT_TEXT(
      P_INPUT    IN VARCHAR2,
      P_TEMPLATE IN VARCHAR2)
    RETURN VARCHAR2
  IS
  BEGIN
    IF P_INPUT IS NOT NULL THEN
      RETURN P_TEMPLATE;
    ELSE
      RETURN NULL;
    END IF;
  END FORMAT_TEXT;
BEGIN
  L_BODY   := '<html> Here I give the HTML Code For Example <p>';
  L_BODY   := L_BODY || FORMAT_TEXT(:P1_ITEM, 'My Text 1: ' || :P1_ITEM || '<br>');
  L_BODY   := L_BODY || FORMAT_TEXT(:P2_ITEM, 'My Text 2: ' || :P2_ITEM || '<br>');
  L_BODY   := L_BODY || FORMAT_TEXT(:P3_ITEM, 'My Text 3: ' || :P3_ITEM || '<br>');
  L_BODY   := L_BODY || '</p> </html>';
  L_FOOTER := '</br></br> Go to Link <a href="URL">link</a>';
  APEX_MAIL.SEND(P_TO => '' || :P1_ITEM || ',' || 'abc@abc.com', P_FROM => 'abc.abc@abc.com', P_BODY => L_BODY || L_FOOTER, P_BODY_HTML=> L_BODY || L_FOOTER, P_SUBJ => 'Text ' || :P1_ITEM || ' ] ');
END;
```

Comment: Hi Kapiell, Thanks for your response. I am new to Oracle Apex environment. And i use the below PLSQL format.

Comment: DECLARE
l_body VARCHAR2(32767);
l_footer VARCHAR2(32767);
 
BEGIN  
l_body:= '<html>  Here i give the HTML Code 
For Example 
<p> My Text ' || :P1_ITEM || ' </p> </html> ';

l_footer:= '<BR><BR> Go to Link <a href="URL">link</a>';
 
apex_mail.send(
        p_to       => '' || :P1_ITEM || ',' ||'abc@abc.com’,
        p_from     => ‘abc.abc@abc.com’,
        p_body     => l_body || l_footer,
        p_body_html=> l_body || l_footer,
         p_subj     => ‘Text ' || :P1_ITEM || ' ]
    ');   
 
 
END;

Comment: Most welcome, Amritha. I have updated my answer, create a routine to conditionally format text of your email body.